# pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1069056-bytes mapped space: Out of memory

Tags: android, android-ndk, out-of-memory

I got an OutOfMemoryError which confuse me for a long time recently. When occur OutOfMemoryError, the process Java heap still have lot of free memory, and the system still have a lot of free memory too. I do a lot of work try to figure it out, but for now, I still have no idea what's wrong.

There are 4 reasons may cause OutOfMemoryError issue: 
1. the process FD number is out of limitation.
2. the process thread number is out of limitation.
3. the process Java heap is full.
4. the process virtual memory is up to 3G in 32 bit system.

I think the most likely reason is 4, so I detect the virtual memory of the process when running the app, I found the virtual memory is close to 3 * 1024 * 1024 byte when OutOfMemoryError occurred. But I don't know why, can anyone give me some direction? Thanks a lot!

Here is the logcat info:

```
04-12 16:15:52.043  9329  9370 W libc    : pthread_create failed: couldn't allocate 1069056-bytes mapped space: Out of memory
04-12 16:15:52.065  9329  9370 W zygote  : Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:    EsrEngine
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.translation.service:offline, PID: 9329
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:733)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.offline.EsrEngine.notifyWriteTask(EsrEngine.java:278)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.offline.EsrEngine.access$600(EsrEngine.java:35)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.offline.EsrEngine$3.run(EsrEngine.java:210)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
04-12 16:15:52.106  9329  9370 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

And here is the code of notifyWriteTask() method.

```
private void notifyWriteTask() {
        isAllowWrite = true;
        final BlockingQueue<byte[]> buffer = databuffer;
        writeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                EsrLogger.d(TAG, "WriteTask lang=" + currentLang
                        + " Run>>>>>>>" + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                        + " dataBuffer=" + buffer.size()
                        + " isAllow=" + isAllowWrite);
                while (isAllowWrite) {
                    byte[] audio;
                    try {
                        audio = buffer.poll(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (!isAllowWrite) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (audio == null) {
                        EsrLogger.w(TAG, "WriteTask No Audio over 1500ms =====> Exit");
                        break;
                    }
                    writeAudio(audio, audio.length);

                    EsrResult result = getEsrResult();
                    if (result != null && result.isFinish()) {
                        databuffer.clear();
                        EsrLogger.d(TAG, "WriteTask has finish result=" + result);
                        writeAudioFlag = EsrInstBase.ESR_AUDIO_END;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                stopEsr();
                buffer.clear();
                EsrLogger.d(TAG, "WriteTask End<<<<<<<<" + writeThread.getId());
            }
        }, currentLang);
        writeThread.start();
        EsrLogger.d(TAG, "WriteTask Start>>>>>>" + writeThread.getId());
    }
```

Comment: "There are 4 reasons may cause OutOfMemoryError issue" -- there are other reasons than the ones that you list, such as not having a contiguous block of memory in the Java heap big enough for your request. Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are triggering this exception, in particular what `notifyWriteTask()` is doing.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is memory fragments. But I'm sure, Memory fragments is not the reason.